# It there a possible way that I could scale all the objects individually?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, groups

I'm working on a complicated building which my goal is to keep the multiple objects in their respective groups and scale all objects at once. Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> function to group everything into 1 object and scale it.

Appreciate some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-J joins the meshes of all select objects into a single object, you could group them by Ctrl-G and select the whole group with Shift-G / Group.

Comment: Welcome ramen :) Please check if the link/question above solves your issue, if not then leave a comment here. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Answer (score 2):

Try simply selecting all your objects and scale the whole selection.
It doesen't work if the pivot point is set to "individual origin".
All the others options will scale your objects maintaining shapes and proportions